How can I make a shader that uses an Image Texture and results in a specific stained wood effect
I have taken photos of Birch wood planks, and used an Image Texture connected to the Principled BDSF node Base Color to model a bookcase.

I would like to try to visualize how it will look with different wood stains applied.
I applied these stains to one piece of scrap birch after having cut a 4'x8' sheet.

When trying to make the 'Dark Walnut' color (top right of the 4 samples) I tried using a ColorRamp node, but this ends up looking pretty bad, either becoming almost uniformly brown, removing the woodgrain, or with extremely bright spots with white tint.


I also tried using the RGB Curves, and this got a closer result, but I was mostly guessing and just tweaking at random.

I am only trying to get a close approximation, because the actual stain can be applied very different depending on how much I allow it to work into the wood. How can I create a shader, that may best approximate how a particular stain color could look on these textures? Alternatively, would it be better to do the work on the source images in a photo editor?

Sorry, but there is no general solution to "best approximate how a particular stain color could look". Especially on organic materials, you have to tweak the settings manually to get the desired outcome, this ominous undefined "particular stain". Sure, general advice like try to change hue and saturation, use RGB curves, a color ramp etc. can be given. But you have tried that and while this can lead to the desired result, there is no specific setting we can tell you that will work for whatever "particular stain color" you choose.

For your issues with the color ramp making it almost uniformly brown and making bright spots with white tint: why do you have bright white in there then? You can make it any color you like. Also you do not have to limit the color ramp to a start and end color, you can place different colors inbetween as well. And you do not have to leave the interpolation at Linear, you can change it to Ease or Bézier for different color distributions.

For the ColorRamp, it did not click with me how to change the colors. I don't practice computer graphics often because I don't enjoy it heh, and when the right-click context menu didn't provide any kind of specific settings for the node, I stopped exploring it. After your comment I checked it again and realized how to change the other end of the gradient.
"best approximate..." was a bad word choice, so I guess a better question would be, 'Are there any nodes that would further help, or are ColorRamp / RGBCurves good places to start?'

Yes, Color Ramps and RGB Curves are a good way to start, also a Hue/Saturation/Value node. On the RGB Curves node you can also manipulate R, G and B channels separately. I do not understand the problem with the Color Ramp... it did not click how to change the colors? You changed a color from black to brown... and did you not wonder what the Plus and Minus buttons are for or the dropdown menus? If you gave up exploring so quickly, you will have a hard time learning Blender and with getting help here as well, because it is expected people show at least some effort on learning the basics.
